# DB backup and restarting the node with the DB backed up file is not working as expected

Tags: database

We are trying to restart the nodes with the DB backup file such as chain data DB, keystore etc these are backed up regularly. But we are getting the below error :

> Error: Service(Client(Backend("Invalid argument: Column families not opened: col11, col10, col9, col8, col7, col6, col5, col4, col3, col2, col1, col0")))

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a sign that the database is corrupted.